# VueJS namespaced Vuex module getter returns incorrect value on page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Under exactly same circumstances I get different outputs of the same getter.

```
console.log(store.getters);
```

Output in the console: `{}: auth/loggedIn: true`, which is the correct value I want to get, but look at this:

```
console.log(store.getters['auth/loggedIn']);
```

Output in the console: `false`

Why is that?

**My `auth.js` module:**

```
auth = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        token: null
    },
    getters: {
        loggedIn(state) {
            return state.token !== null
        }, ...
```

**My `app.js`**:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue'
...
import routes from './routes'
import {store} from './store/store'
 ...
console.log(store.getters['auth/loggedIn']);
```

Comment: When you log objects in the console it will hold a reference to that object and show its value at the time you are viewing it, _not_ its value at the time it was logged. My guess is that at the point you are logging `store.getters` the value of the `auth/loggedIn` property is actually `false` (since that's what gets logged when you log the value of the property itself), but that it has been updated by the time you view the object in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thanksd pointed out, logging objects in the console shows the values at the viewing time. The real value of the property was actually false. Changing the lifecycle of the application solved the issue.